Reading from a file opened by another application
I have an application that reads a CSV file.
If the file is opened in another application, such as Excel, I get the following error message:
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\tmatthews\Documents\Voyant 3\Issue 1943\RF00_ENC_RFF.csv' because it is being used by another process.'

I'm using the C# function StreamReader:
       using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(m_filename))
How can I read from the file when it is opened in another application (using C#)?
